# When is this proverb used? Ein blindes Huhn findet auch mal ein Korn

Tags: german-to-english, proverb

Recently I've been reading one german user in a forum saying the following:

> Ein blindes Huhn findet auch mal ein Korn.

A user replied immediatly

> Besser ein blindes Huhn als auf dem rechten Auge blind.

When does it is used?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. If you are just asking about the meaning and translation, this is off-topic here. However, there is an underlying proverb to each that would make the question on-topic again. If you know what the direct translation is and edit it in, I’m sure closure can be prevented. And *pro forma*, here are the traditional links to the [tour] and [help] ;)

Comment: The only translation I know is the one from Google translate (that seems wrong).. could you please add it to make it in topic? I just need to know where this proverb used and why to understand it contextually

Comment: Google Translate does a remarkably good job of capturing the words correctly and providing a good literal translation if you ask me ;)

Comment: _"could you please add it to make it in topic?"_ I'm not sure, but in case you're asking @Jan to edit your question: you can do that yourself. Just hit the [edit] link below your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proverb

> Ein blindes Huhn findet auch 'mal ein Korn.

translates to something like

> Even a blind chicken stumbles across a grain from time to time.

The meaning basically is, even somebody who isn't that competent gets something right from time to time.

The response seems to be a play on words.

> Besser ein blindes Huhn als auf dem rechten Auge blind.

translates to something like

> Better to be a blind chicken then to be blind in right eye.

"Auf dem rechten Auge blind sein" is a phrase that basically means to (willfully) turn a blind eye to "the right" (neonazis, far-right extremists etc.) and their propaganda and assaults.

Answer (score 2):

> Ein blindes Huhn findet auch mal ein Korn.

*Even a blind chicken picks up a grain now and then.*

I'm pretty sure this is self-explaining. It's used as an accusation that someone has a history of being wrong all the time and brags heavily about being right this one time.

> Besser ein blindes Huhn als auf dem rechten Auge blind.

This isn't a proverb but a counter-accusation. The person bragging about being correct says the other person has a history of having blind eye himself for (illegal) activities of right-wingers.

Comment: "Ein blindes Huhn findet auch mal ein Korn" is on no way an accusation.

Comment: When do you use it?

Comment: In the same context as you stated, but rather with the background of pitying him, for example.

Comment: Pitying him? Now you're sarcastic.

Comment: not the least bit.

Comment: I cannot think of a situation where I truly *pity* someone with that speaking. I can hardly think of a situation in which Mr. T *pity the fool…* with that sentence. I can only see it sarcastic and accusing. The latter especially in an online discussion.